# Service (grafana-server) does not start automatically on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, autostart

I have a problem with autostarting Grafana on Ubuntu 16.04 (while it starts automatically on 14.04, also other added services on 16.04 configured in a similar way do start automatically).

I ran configuration as below:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d grafana-server defaults
```

No output from the command (running multiple times does not print any new information):

```
$ sudo update-rc.d grafana-server defaults
$ sudo update-rc.d grafana-server defaults
$
$ sudo reboot
```

After restart the service is stopped (if I delete `/var/log/grafana/grafana.log` before reboot, it is not created). The status is:

```
$ sudo service grafana-server status
● grafana-server.service - Starts and stops a single grafana instance on this system
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/grafana-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: http://docs.grafana.org
```

And the service starts up when called manually:

```
$ sudo service grafana-server status
● grafana-server.service - Starts and stops a single grafana instance on this system
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/grafana-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2016-07-17 23:07:33 JST; 1s ago
     Docs: http://docs.grafana.org
 Main PID: 2658 (grafana-server)
    Tasks: 7 (limit: 512)
   Memory: 23.0M
      CPU: 105ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/grafana-server.service
           └─2658 /usr/sbin/grafana-server --config=/etc/grafana/grafana.ini --pidfile= cfg:default.paths.logs=/var/log/grafana cfg:de
```

After another reboot, it does not start.

Startup scripts in `init.d` are present:

```
$ ls -l /etc/rc3.d/*grafana*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 24 Jul 17 22:58 /etc/rc3.d/S04grafana-server -> ../init.d/grafana-server*
$ ls -l /etc/init.d/grafana-server
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root 3291 Jul 12 19:57 /etc/init.d/grafana-server*
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 6):

check if `/etc/systemd/system/grafana-server.service` if a correct link to `/lib/systemd/system/grafana-server.service`

If not, create `/lib/systemd/system/grafana-server.service`
the source file is here : https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/packaging/deb/systemd/grafana-server.service

Then create the correct link :

```
sudo ln -s /lib/systemd/system/grafana-server.service /etc/systemd/system/grafana-server.service
```

Then enable grafana-server

```
sudo systemctl enable grafana-server
```

Then start grafana-server

```
sudo systemctl start grafana-server
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running this command:

```
sudo systemctl enable grafana-server.service
```

I was having same issue as you (clean install of 16.04)
Notice the output from your service status:

```
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/grafana-server.service; disabled
```

Which is indicating that the service is disabled. The command above fixed the issue for me.

[Source](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/debian/)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this on Ubuntu 18.04 today and it was because `grafana-server.service` is `After=network-online.target` and the system hadn't reached `network-online.target` because `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` was still running and hadn't timed out yet.

I got around this with `systemctl mask systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` as my grafana instance and my InfluxDB instance are on the same server.